# Server-Side Rendering in SharePoint 2013 Content Search Web Part Without XSLT?

Tags: web-part, asp.net, 2013

**Background:** I am new to SharePoint and I recently attended the SharePoint 2012 conference. It seems the primary way to render content in a custom way is on the client-side via JavaScript in the Content Search Web Part (CSWP). However, there is also a way to do it on the server-side, using XSLT. Rendering on the server is the primary method I'd like to use.

**Question:** I used XSLT a bunch with Umbraco (a CMS), and it worked most of the time, but I prefer to render on the server using ASP.Net markup. Is this possible to do in the CSWP?

**Contingency:** Is there another web part that allows this? Do I need to build my own web part? If so, can I expose the same capabilities to users to query content the same way they do with the CSWP.

Answer (score 2):

1- CSWP is based on display templates which uses client side rendering so you can't use display templates to render on server side

2- You can use XSLT to render server side and here is an article of how to do it http://www.mavention.com/blog/server-side-rendering-content-search-web-part-sharepoint-2013

3- There is no out of the box web part that support asp.net server side rendering however you can achieve this by creating visual web part with any data access way like CAML Queries from inside Visual Studio 
The following article describe using CAML Query to retrieve list items
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx

The following article describe the options to create web parts inside SharePoint 2010 with sample
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857549(v=office.14).aspx

4- It is possible to build server side rendering by querying search index and here is an article that describe how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use following options:

1) You can use CAML rendering to customize your list forms as you want. Please see the example here: http://sp2013.blogspot.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-list-custom-form.html.

2) You can use AllUserWebPart for your list forms.

3) You can customize list form rendering templates.

Thanks,
Himanshu.